# How to overcome this error :Cannot read property 'selectize' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, selectize.js

I keep receiving errors as mentioned in the question at this line of js:

```
  var $filter = $('#share_tags')[0].selectize;
```

The related html is also attached alongside..

```js
(function() {
 // Extra symbols for our share expression
 var symbols = ['+','|','~','(',')'],
  symbolCount = {};
 // Initialize all symbols count to 0
 symbols.forEach(function(s) {
  symbolCount[s] = 0;
 });
 // our ops
 var ops = [
  { value: '+', text: 'AND', symbol:true },
  { value: '|', text: 'OR', symbol: true },
  { value: '~', text: 'NOT', symbol: true },
  { value: '(', text: '(', symbol: true },
  { value: ')', text: ')', symbol: true }
 ];

 function getText(value) {
  for(var i = 0, len = ops.length; i < len; i += 1) {
   if (ops[i].value === value) {
    return ops[i].text;
   }
  }
 }

 // User select
 $('#share_with').selectize({
  openOnFocus: false,
 });

 // Tag select
 $('#share_tags').selectize({
  persist: false,
  onItemAdd: function(value, $item) {
   if (symbolCount.hasOwnProperty(value[0])) {
    var value = value[0],
     count = symbolCount[value];
    $filter.addOption({
     value: value + '' + (count+1),
     text: getText(value)
    });
    symbolCount[value] += 1;
    $filter.refreshOptions();
   }
  },
  onItemRemove: function(item) {
   if (symbolCount.hasOwnProperty(item[0]) !== -1) {
    for (opt in $filter.options) {
     if ($filter.options.hasOwnProperty(opt)) {
      if (opt !== item && opt[0] === item) {
       delete $filter.options[opt];
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 });

 var $filter = $('#share_tags')[0].selectize;

 $('#shareForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  var tags = $('#share_tags').val(),
   expression = [],
   symbol,
   item;

  for (var i = 0, len = tags.length; i < len; i += 1) {
   item = tags[i];
   if (symbolCount.hasOwnProperty(item[0]) !== -1) {
    symbol = item[0] === '+' ? '&' : item[0];
    expression.push(symbol);
   }
   else {
    expression.push(item);
   }
  }
  $('#share_expression').val(expression.join(''));
 });

 
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
        $(".search-card").removeClass("hide");
    }   // esc
    });

    $('.js-share-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        $(".search-card").addClass("hide");
        App.Util.preventDefault(e);
        Avgrund.show("#createShare");
    });

    $('.edit-share-button').on('click', function(e) {
        $(".search-card").addClass("hide");
        App.Util.preventDefault(e);
        Avgrund.show("#createTaskShare");       
        });
    
    $(".js-popup-close").on("click",function () {
        $(".search-card").removeClass("hide");
    });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% set created_tags = [t for t in tags if t.tag.created_by == current_user] %}
<form name="shareForm" id="shareForm" method="post" action="/share/new">
 <fieldset>
  <h3>Share card</h3>
 </fieldset>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="share_name">Card name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="share_name" id="share_name" required="required">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="share_tags">Tag</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="share_tags" id="share_tags" required="required" placeholder="Pick a tag to share">
   {% if q[0] == '#' %}
   {% set name, id = q.split("/") %}
   <option value="{{ id }}">{{ name }}</option>
   {% end %}
  </select>
  {#
  <select class="form-control" name="share_tags" id="share_tags" required="required" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Pick a tag to share">
   <option value=""></option>
   <optgroup label="Tags">
    {% for t in created_tags %}
    <option value="{{ t.tag.id }}">{{ t.tag.name }}</option>
    {% end %}
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Filters">
    <option value='+'>AND</option>
    <option value='|'>OR</option>
    <option value='~'>NOT</option>
    <option value='('>(</option>
    <option value=')'>)</option>
   </optgroup>
  </select>
  #}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="share_with">Share with</label>
  <select class="input-control" name="share_with" id="share_with" required="required" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Choose a few people">
   <option value="">Select a user</option>
   {% for user in contacts %}
    {% if user.id != 1 %}
    <option value="{{ user.id }}">{{ user.name }} &lt;{{ user.email }}&gt;</option>
    {% end %}
   {% end %}
  </select>
 </div>
 {% module xsrf_form_html() %}
 <input type="hidden" name="share_expression" id="share_expression" value="">
 <div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary share-btn">Share</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn-link js-popup-close">Cancel</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Selectize is a Jquery plugin. If you don't import it, you will not be able to use it. (that is the error, your objects don't have a selectize property).

You can see the [plugin page](http://plugins.jquery.com/selectize/), or it's [github](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js).

Download it [here](http://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/zipball/v0.11.0) and try it.

Remember to add the following lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="selectize.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="selectize.css" />
```

Comment: Just for the record I am having the exact same problem and it is not due to a missing import... if I have the selectize code in the view within the <script> tag, it works fine but I change it to a separate JS file and now...

Comment: Again... just found the problem... a copy/paste problem, wrong `selectize` id... in the end it all comes down to the fact that `selectize` wasn't found properly.